# VS2010 Build Fail with error: Cannot open 'PathToFile.rsp'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild

I'm having a problem when trying to build my project and i don't know where to look.
The problem is that the build fails every time. it gives me the following error

[Error messages on build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHHBQ.jpg)

When I searched for those files I found that they weren't in that folder
The strangest thing is that if i build the same project on the visual studio, or if I run MSBuild from Visual Studio 2010 command line the project builds without problem. Also, I have configured another builder in another computer, and when I run the build there with the same Build definition it builds correctly. My guess is that it have to be some configuration that i'm missing, but I don't know where to look.

The computer is running Windows Server 2012

Comment: It seems your issue is not related to your project, but the environment of your build agent machine. Try to login the build agent machine that builds are failed, and run MSBuild command line to build the project on this machine to see whether you'll get a successful build.

Comment: Hello @Cece-MSFT -MSFT, thanks for your response.
We tried to build the solution using MSBuild from the command line, with the same parameters we use in the tfs build and it builded without problems

Comment: Did you build the solution that in the agent working folder or you copied  from your machine?